# Node JS - How can I get the value outside the function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server, alexa-skills-kit

I'm trying to get the value of the variable "Ajuste" outside the function, because I need Alexa to say it in the last return of the other function.

The value of the "Ajuste" variable should be used in the "speakOutput" variable that is outside that function, but finally it shows me that the value is `undefined`.

This is the fragment that I have problems with, the connection to the database is fine and the query is also executed without problems because the value that `console.log(result.recordset [0] .Consecutive);` it is right.

```js
var Inventario = {
  user: 'user',
  password: 'pass',
  server: 'server\\instance',
  database: 'db'
};

const InventarioIngresoIntentHandler = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    return Alexa.getRequestType(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'IntentRequest' &&
      Alexa.getIntentName(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'InventarioIngresoIntent';
  },
  handle(handlerInput) {
    var DocInventario = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.slots.Documento.value
    var Ajuste;
    sql.connect(Inventario, function(err) {
      if (err) console.log(err);
      var request = new sql.Request();
      request.query('select * from Ajuste Where ConsecutivoExterno =' + DocInventario, function(err, result) {
        if (err) console.log(err)
        console.log(result.recordset[0].Consecutivo);
        console.log(result.recordset[0].ConsecutivoExterno);
        Ajuste = result.recordset[0].Consecutivo;
        sql.close();
      })
    });
    const speakOutput = Ajuste + ', Correcto.' + DocInventario
    return handlerInput.responseBuilder
      .speak(speakOutput)
      .withSimpleCard(SkillName, speakOutput)
      .reprompt(speakOutput)
      .getResponse();
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

let the Ajuste property in a scope common to all the methods. I change var to const because `var` have an unexpected behavior sometimes because it isn't block scoped.

```js
const InventarioIngresoIntentHandler = {
  Ajuste: undefined,
  showAjuste() {
    this.Ajuste = "New Value";
    console.log(this.Ajuste)
  },
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    return Alexa.getRequestType(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'IntentRequest' &&
      Alexa.getIntentName(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'InventarioIngresoIntent';
  },
  handle(handlerInput) {
    const DocInventario = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.slots.Documento.value
    
    sql.connect(Inventario, function(err) {
      if (err) console.log(err);
      const request = new sql.Request();
      request.query('select * from Ajuste Where ConsecutivoExterno =' + DocInventario, function(err, result) {
        if (err) console.log(err)
        
        this.Ajuste = result.recordset[0].Consecutivo;
        sql.close();
      })
    });
    const speakOutput = this.Ajuste + ', Correcto.' + DocInventario
    return handlerInput.responseBuilder
      .speak(speakOutput)
      .withSimpleCard(SkillName, speakOutput)
      .reprompt(speakOutput)
      .getResponse();
  }
};

InventarioIngresoIntentHandler.showAjuste()
```

Comment: Hi.
I apply the changes that you made but when adding InventarioIngresoIntentHandler.showAjuste () the Skill stops responding.
With the rest of the changes the final value of "this.Ajuste" is "undefined" and inside the function it takes the normal values.

Comment: Hi, you can add a default value to this.Ajuste if you need use it before use a method that give a value to that value. If this question help you, you can select it as the correct answer :)

Comment: The value of the variable Ajuste continues to be different, I think it may also be because I couldn't invoke the showAdjust function because when I add that line of the code the skill stops responding.